# Как использовать Pygame в QPython?

Tags: android, python, python-2.x, pygame, qpython

Известно что простой pygame на андроиде (QPython - python для андроид) при попытке использования выводит `Sigmentation fault.` Но в QPython встроен kivy который, по некоторым источникам, использует pygame для рендера. Так как же использовать pygame?

Comment: Кivy, насколько мне известно, уже перешел на SDL, последнии остатки PyGame их него активно выпиливаются!

Comment: @Xyanight, в QPython python2

Comment: @xyanight, допустим. Но вопрос в том как использовать pygame на QPython.

Comment: Я давненько бросил заниматься эксперементами с Python непомредственно на смарте, но помниться, что пакет PyGame под него был и прекрасно себе работал... Опять же, при сборке apk для Андрюшки также можно использовать PyGame...

Comment: @Xyanight, у меня выдаёт Sigmentation fault.

Comment: Вы используете Pygame Subset for Android?

Comment: @Xyanight, в QPython встроен pygame. И называется он там `pygame`. А pip  `pygame subject for android` не находит..

Comment: Для Pygame надо установить SLD